# Pre-existing set of 'useful' customizations for Emacs (CLI version)?

Tags: emacs

I'm sat here getting emacs into some sort of usable form, with line numbers, less annoying backup file handling and syntax highlighting.  Intent on not repeating the process, I was going to push the entire set of changes into a git repository for easy re-use.  But presumably somebody else has already done this and many people just use a 'standard' set of customizations?  Is there a place I can simply download a tarball and extract it to my home directory and be done?

I work primarily with Ruby, Python, PHP and C, so don't need anything too magical.

Comment: emacs-starter-kit? https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit.git

Comment: The Emacs Wiki would be a good place to look. http://www.emacswiki.org/ Your definition of "useful" probably differs from most everybody else's. Also googling for `.emacs` should get you a good sampler of the variability of everybody else's definition.

Comment: @fardjad, you should make that an answer, it's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer as requested:

You can use this [`Emacs Starter Kit`](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit.git).